# What is this small tree with purple leaves and small green fruits?

Tags: identification, trees

I'd like to get one of these for my back yard but I'm not sure what kind of tree it is... anybody know?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is [Purple Leaf Plum, *Prunus cerasifera*.](http://www.arborday.org/treeguide/treeDetail.cfm?ID=157) The fruits will drop after coloring, so this is classed as a messy tree, but I agree it is attractive.

Here are some comparison photos:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This could also be prunus virginiana schubert.  This tree  to 9 meters tall by 5 m spread has purple foliage and white flowers.

Comment: @kevinsky check out the flower stem structure of *P. virginiana* 'schubert': http://www.eutopiagardens.org/latest/eutopia_biota/images/imported/bibldb/bibldb_82206_1178_15494-Prunus%20Schubert.jpg I think the flowers of that one branch off a flower stem, whereas *P. cerasifera* flowers come directly from the old bud wood, or from a smaller stem.

Comment: I have trouble telling where the flowering stems attach. It's definitely a Prunus species and you are right they can be messy. Best planted away from paths.